# Camera on transporter of population

Tags: camera, simulation, anylogic

I want to put a camera on a transporter of an agent type AGV. Since there are multiple AGV transporters I cannot simply put it on the agent since it will give errors.
So I tried to randomly select an AGV of the population, based on the busy parameter of the AGV agent. But when I try this it gives the next error: AGV can not be resolved to a variable.

AGV is an Agent type in my model and I've created a transporter fleet with as agent type the AGV (I also do not know if this is the correct method).

I've tried to code it in the following manner:

[image: Code of transporterfleetpart]

[image: Code of selecting a camera]

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong, but I also could not find any simple example of putting a camera on AGVs or containers or something, only very complex examples or examples where there was just one agent (e.g. an airplane).

Later added:

[image: Camerasettings]
[image: Gray screen]

Thanks in advance,
Aron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you need to provide a population for the randomWhere function

[image]

And to add newly generated transporters to a population simply set it up in the transporter fleet

[image]

The easiest option to follow any agent is to have a camera inside the agent

[image]

And then in your code you simply set the 3DWindow camera to the camera of the selected AGV (You add true to the last parameter so that the 3D window follows the camera location)

[image]

Also check out the code in this model where AnyLogic implemented the follow camera logic in detail

https://cloud.anylogic.com/model/3291f1d6-d388-4d18-9060-29fad93d651d?mode=SETTINGS

Also in the example models inside AnyLogic

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look at it.

Comment: I also tried your method @Jaco-Ben, the same problem exists, that I just see a gray visualization when I switch to the camera.

Comment: My assumption was that you already had this part covered as it was not in the question - see my updated answer

Comment: I really tried this, but the strange thing is the camera seems to move but is definitely not following my AGV but something else, which shows the visualization from further away..
Is it possible to upload your simple example, so that I can check step by step which setting I'm setting wrong, since something seems not correct in my model.. Thanks already @jaco-ben

Comment: Have a look here https://cloud.anylogic.com/model/ede1b3ca-4d1a-4fbe-ab08-5417886edbc4?mode=SETTINGS, also check out the link I gave to the other example, you might need to tilt the camera bit or rotate as you need.

Comment: Thanks, I see! Is it also possible to share the anylogic file instead of the simulation, so I can see all the settings. I checked the other example indeed, but since the example is way more complex it is hard to compare step by step and see which mistake I made in the settings

Comment: @AronT. I have made the model source files downloadable - You can also contact me directly more options

Comment: Thanks I found the mistake! It the position of the representation of your population in this case the AGV population. You have to put it in the middle of the box otherwise it won't follow the middle of the screen! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help, if you found my answer useful, remember to accept it, and upvote if you found it worthy ;-)

Comment: I will definitely do, but since I'm new I first need to get 15 reputation to do that haha!

Answer (score 2):

Just put the camera into your AGV agent type. Make sure that your TransporterFleet is adding new transporters to a custom population of AGV agents (`myPop`), see below:
[image]

In your model, you can now change the camera using `my3DWindow.setCamera(((AGV)randomFrom(myPop)).myCamera);`

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin! I will have a look at it!

Comment: I tried your method, also in a less complex model. I've created the population with agent type AGV and put a camera in the agent type, it now works with no errors, the only thing is when watching the window3d it now only shows a grey visualization, no AGV or something is shown, should I change my camera setting? I've added a picture of the original camera settings in my first post and also added the grey camera screen.

Comment: as per JBs reply, you need to position the camera such that it looks your AGV animation "over the shoulder", if that is what you need. If the reply was helpful, please upvote it, helps others with similar problems to find it easier in the future, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Comment: Thanks @benjamin I know, but since I'm new to stackoverflow I'm not allowed to upvote, I will definitly do this in the future!